# FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH for an URI in firefox android extension

Tags: android, sqlite, firefox-addon, storage

I'm developing an extention for firefox on android,it's my first attempt and I'm facing hard times, I'm trying to store some data on sqlite file, using the [Mozilla storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage) to access and store in an sqlite file that exists in the download directory by using the extension. I tried this code

```
var f = new FileUtils.File("file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/bd.sqlite");
file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", [f]);   
mDBConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file); 
let stmt = mDBConn.createStatement("INSERT INTO try (k,url,track) VALUES(1,'twitter',12)");
stmt.executeAsync();
```

and I'm getting this error:

> `E/GeckoConsole( 7345): [JavaScript Error: "NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH: Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath]" {file: "resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/sru26yxk.default/extensions/trackDetect@fst.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js" line: 322}]`

I'm really lost, I know there is a problem with the path but, it is the right one, I think the problem is how to transform the string path to an URI that can be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new FileUtils.File()` creates an [`nsIFile` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFile), not [`nsIURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIURI). Consequently, you have to pass a file path to it, not a URI:

```
var f = new FileUtils.File("/storage/sdcard0/Download/bd.sqlite");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, now, I can get the file, but a new error appeared and it's pointing this code line: 
let stmt = mDBConn.createStatement("INSERT INTO try (k,url,track) VALUES(1,'twitter',12)");
the error is  "NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]"

Comment: I simply don't have enough experience with storage to tell you what might be wrong here, ask a new question?

Comment: Btw, according to documentation: "If the statement is meant to be executed asynchronously, you should rather create it with createAsyncStatement."

Comment: Thanks again Wladimir, I'll try to figure it out or post a new question. Really thak you.